# Unconstrained Optimization using Gradient and (sparse) Hessian

Tags: optimization, c++

I'm looking for a C++ optimization package that can do multivariate unconstrained optimization using gradient and Hessian information.  I'm doing it now in Matlab using fminunc with the 'GradObj', 'Hessian', and 'HessPattern' options.  My Hessian is very sparse so a package that takes that into account would be preferable.

Are there any alternatives to Matlab for this?  Open-source or closed-source are both fine.  C++ is preferable but I'm flexible.

Comment: Would this receive more attention on StackOverflow?  What kind of optimization are you looking to do?  "Unconstrained multivariate" doesn't narrow it down very much - do you mean that it's applicable to any twice differentiable function?  The reason I ask is that some optimizers may be better for certain classes of problems, especially where sparsity can be exploited.

Comment: It's basically a photogrammetry-based bundle adjustment problem.  There are hundreds of variables to optimize over, but most variables only interact with small numbers of other variables, leading to a sparse Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered compiling the MATLAB library into a .dll or .exe that R can reference? MATLAB has this capability.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, but MATLAB is a pretty big dependency to carry around and I've been tasked with finding alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could just ditch the Hessian and use a BFGS approach, like [libLBFGS](http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/). These quasi-Newton methods are usually pretty good.

Comment: That might be a good option.  I'll have to see if performance suffers.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you need is an efficient linear algebra library. Consider, for example, [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the [trustOptim](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trustOptim/vignettes/trustOptim.pdf) package in R. It is useful in case the Hessian is sparse. As far as I know, the core of that package is written in C++ and interfaced with R using Rcpp. It's open source as well.